# Hibernate SetParameter driving me nuts

Tags: hibernate, hql

This works

```
hql = "from State where StateCode like 'T%'";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
```

This does not

```
hql = "from State where StateCode like :StateCode";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("StateCode", "T%");
```

I get this

```
1568 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter  - throwQueryException() : no errors
1596 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker  - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
1608 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement  - FromClause{level=1} :  com.kencogroup.kkms.models.State (no alias) -> state0_
1610 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode  - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias} -> {synthetic-alias}
1611 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode  - getDataType() : StateCode -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@a39137
1611 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode  - Resolved :  {synthetic-alias}.StateCode -> state0_.StateCode
SELECT Exception: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

Notice the `UndeclaredThrowableException` exception.

What am I doing wrong?

The database is SQL Server 2008 if that helps.  But like I said, other queries work just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: I mean stacktrace of the exception, not log.

Comment: And you should also show us the source code of the State entity

Comment: Here is a gist of the State source code, the AbstractRepository source code, the stack trace (as best I can tell), etc.  https://gist.github.com/866389     I am trying to achieve something like: `stateRepo.like("StateCode", "TN").select();` and `stateRepo.like("StateCode", "TN").like("AccountingCode", 25).select();` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY!

Turns out, the version of ANTLR in Struts 1 was different than the version of Hibernate.  TOTAL confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the standard naming conventions, it should be `stateCode`, and not `StateCode`.
Try with

```
hql = "from State where stateCode like :myStateCode";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("myStateCode", "T%");
```